# how to show different captions with youtube api v3

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, caption, subtitle

i'm making a webapp of video series. I'm using youtube api v3 to display the videos, but i need the ability to choice between 3 different subtitle and i can't find the answer in youtube docs.
Any example? Ideas?

Comment: AFAIK, captions aren't yet available in V3 of the YouTube API.

Comment: You can use other player like videojs  that has a subtitle functionality. The only problem is you need to do create a subtitle for it.